# GtkDialogBox doesnot appear on trying to open again

Tags: c, gtk3

Once a GtkDialogBox is open by clicking a menu item, it successfully appears. After closing the dialog box if it is again tried to open, it fails, a mini box containing nothing shows. what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Its either wrong button-response id or you didn't connect the signal from you GtkDialog, i.e

```
g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), dialog);
```

Since you did not post any code, there's limit of how people can help you.